# Show messagebox after data insertion

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I am new to vb.net (VS 2008) & need a help. I am feeding data from windows form to mysql dbase..
upon successful data insertion it sud show "data added" in msgbox
how to do it ?> 
Please help.

This is my button code

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Manage("insert into pExpenses(expdate,exptype,expamount) values('" & txtExpDate.Text & "','" & txtExpType.Text & "'," & txtExpAmount.Text & ")")
    End Sub
```

On clicking, data is fed to the database but i need a confirmation in the form of messagebox. Please help.

Comment: google is your friend http://goo.gl/6FSab

Comment: You are opening yourself up to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) problems if you do not use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

As you stated, you are using MySQL database as back-end for you VB.net application. If you are calling manage() function to insert data, Look for ".ExecuteNonQuery()" function calling to insert the data. This ExecuteNonQuery() function always return the number of rows affected during the command execution. Assign that return value to an Integer variable, Check if it is greater than 0, then show the message.

```
Dim insRet as integer = <MySqlCommandobject>.ExecuteNonQuery()
If insRet>0 then
messagebox.show(insret & " Record(s) Successfully Inserted")
else
messagebox.show("Records not inserted")
End If
```